# How to get the dropdown selected text in linq to sql?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, webforms

I bound the column names in dropdownlist. I need to get the selected dropdown text using linq to sql .please tell me......

thanks in advance..

Comment: What does LINQ to SQL have to do with it?  You can get the selected text from a drop down list by a property on the drop down list itself.  It's not clear what you're really trying to do.  Can you show some code of how you're _attempting_ to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just as confused as David in the comments- you need to give more detail. But I'll give it a shot.

Let's say for example that you have a DropDownList that is bound to a SqlDataSource. When you select an item from the DropDownList, then you have a GridView below that changes content based on what you selected in the DropDownList.
Your GridView will have its own SqlDataSource object. If it doesn't, select it and hit the little ">" on the right to open the actions window. From there, set up the SqlDataSource just like you did with the DropDownList, but point it at the database table that the grid cares about. In one of the screens, there will be a WHERE button. Use that dialog to set it up.

For example, the DropDownList gets a list of Departments and you want to show Employees in that department. For the GridView, point its SqlDataSource at the Employee table. In the WHERE dialog box, set Column = DepartmentId (foreign key), Operator = "=", and Source = Control. Then on the right, pick the DropDownList from the Control list, and click Add below. That will automatically send down the selected item whenever the user changes the selected item. Nothing to set up, it just works.